# Unable to validate email token in other action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am simply trying to validate a token using another action in my controller.

In one action, I generate the token and redirect to another action.

```
string token = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
string userId = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(user.Id);
string emailToken = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token);
return RedirectToAction("TestToken", new { userId = userId, emailToken = emailToken });
```

In the `TestToken` action, I decode the attributes and try to confirm it, but the `result` is always false, with the error `Invalid token.`

```
string decodedUserId = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(userId);
string decodedToken = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(emailToken);
IdentityResult result = await userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(decodedUserId, decodedToken);
```

If I, instead of redirecting to the `TestToken` action, just put the code right after the first, the validation succeeds... What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the examples provided in the following links

[Create a secure ASP.NET MVC 5 web app with log in, email confirmation and password reset (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset#require)

[Account Confirmation and Password Recovery with ASP.NET Identity (C#)](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity#email)

you will see that they do not encode

```
string token = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
return RedirectToAction("TestToken", new { userId = user.Id, emailToken = token });
```

or decode the user id or token.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TestToken(string userId, string emailToken ) {
    //... Code removed for brevity
    IdentityResult result = await userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, emailToken );        
    //... Code removed for brevity
    return View();
}
```